How to open Recordset in .vbs?
I am trying to convert a .wsf to a .vbs.
In the .vbs that the .wsj has as a source, the below works fine:
Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRS.Open "SELECT * FROM " & strTableName2, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

The recordset is created by pointing at a blank text file that gets created a few lines earlier. From there, objRS.AddNew is used to add to the blank RS and objRS.Update is ran which I'm guessing effectively writes the data to the file.
When I move all of the code to just vbs, the objRS.Open gives the error "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another."
The objConnection is created by
strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & destinationFolder & ";" & "Extended Properties=""text"""   
objConnection.Open strConnectionString

The file being opened for objRS is an empty .txt file, in case that matters.
The only thing not copied over from the .wsj is:
<reference object="ADODB.Recordset" />
<reference object="Atoll.Application" />

Which I couldn't see how it was being used anywhere.
I'm having trouble finding the documentation for creating a recordset in vbscript. I do know that if I remove all 3 ad things, it works for a few more lines until it gives me an error saying that the recordset can't be updated.
Edit: In the meantime, I am looking through this to look at which parameters should be changed.
Edit2: Requested test script showing issue below.
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
destinationFolder = "D:\"
strTableName2="PropagationModels.txt"
strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & destinationFolder & ";" & "Extended Properties=""text"""   
objConnection.Open strConnectionString

Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRS.Open "SELECT * FROM " & strTableName2, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

Edit Solution:
As was mentioned in the comments by LesFerch and user692942, the ultimate root cause of this issue is that the .wsf file has access to libraries that the .vbs doesn't. As such all of the adXXXXX references failed. Solution was to add all of the ones I needed as constants for the entire code sheet as shown below.
Const adCmdText = 1
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2


@LesFerch Good catch, my bad. I fixed it in the question but yes, it is a .wsf. Not sure why I started thinking it was .wsj.

You didn't say why you're changing from .wsf to .vbs, but another option is to convert to .js (JScript) and that should have a little more life ahead than VBScript. Anyhow, if the code in the .wsf is vbs code, in general it should be an easy conversion. If you can post a complete sample script (with necessary sample data) that exhibits the error, that will make it much easier to provide help.

I am changing it because apparantly running .wsf files causes some problems for IT. I don't know exactly what they see that they don't like. Also, test script code added.

It looks like reference object="ADODB.Recordset" is needed to use adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText. Try it with hard-coded integers. For example: objRS.Open "SELECT * FROM " & strTableName2, objConnection, 1, 3, 1

@LesFerch Hard coded integers? That’s your advice? Just add the constants locally to the script the difference is the WSF contains the Type Library reference which gives you access to the named constants, unfortunately VBScript doesn’t support Type Libraries other then the ones in it’s own scripting runtime which the MDAC is not part of. Using integers will work but it’s a lot cleaner to add the constants locally that way you know exactly what is doing what.

Does this answer your question? How to use excel built-in constant in VBS (this applies to any external library not just Excel)

@user692942 it was just meant as a quick troubleshooting step, but thanks for providing the complete answer.

That makes sense but the trouble with that is you are fundamentally changing the code making it easier to make a mistake whereas named constants just need adding at the top of the script without any further changes to the code. Reading between the lines it sounds like the OP has already tried adjusting the code which will lead to other problems. If it worked in WSF it should work in VBScript with the caveat that the named constants are declared.
